# Verb + ことが○○です vs verb + 〇〇です

Tags: grammar, particle-こと

What is the difference between `Verb + ことが○○です` and `verb + 〇〇です`? And when are you supposed to use one over the other?

For example I wrote

```
映画を観ることが時間です。
It's time to watch a movie.
```

But I was corrected to

> 映画を観る時間です。

But I don't really understand why. I thought `こと` is used to signify some kind of event. In this `時間です (It's time)` and the event is `映画を観る (watch/watching a movie)`

Comment: If so, where the が comes from, and what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually don't like to draw analogies between Japanese and other languages, but here it's almost a 100% fit with English.

> 映画を観る
>
> To watch a movie (dictionary form)

> 時間です。
>
> It is time.

Combine both together and you get:

> 映画を観る時間です。
>
> It is time to watch a movie.

Comment: Alternatively, "It is movie-watching time." Conversely, 映画を観ること is "the act of watching a movie", or simply "watching a movie", and using が after it pretty much dictates that's where the "is" should go. If これはペンです is "This is a pen", then 映画を見ることが時間です means "Watching a movie *is* time". Which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: (The use of が instead of は makes it even slightly more odd, as it kind of implies that someone was wondering *what* time is, and you answered with "Watching a movie, *that's* time.)